# Laravel Vapor deploys and then fails to respond to requests

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, laravel-vapor

I just deployed a Laravel App using Vapor, and received the following message. I don't believe that I changed anything (a few html blade lines).

> Caching Laravel configuration{"message":"Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::__construct()
>   must be of the type int, string given, called in
>   /var/task/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php
>   on line
>   1014","context":{"exception":{"class":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError","message":"Argument
>   1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::__construct()
>   must be of the type int, string given, called in
>   /var/task/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php
>   on line
>   1014","code":0,"file":"/var/task/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Exception/HttpException.php:24"},"aws_request_id":null},"level":400,"level_name":"ERROR","channel":"production","datetime":"2019-09-27T13:18:45.338555+00:00","extra":{}}

The website now just shows `{"message": "Internal server error"}`

Did I do this, or is this a Laravel/Vapor bug?

Comment: It might be worth someone creating a `laravel-vapor` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you use gateway_version 2. As per vapors documentation, you need to use an external DNS like Cloudflare for HTTPS redirection. https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/environments.html#gateway-versions

> If you choose to use API Gateway 2.0 and would like to support HTTP to
> HTTPS redirection, we currently suggest using Cloudflare as an
> external DNS provider for your Vapor application. Cloudflare not only
> provides DNS, but serves as a reverse proxy to your application and
> features an option for automatic HTTP to HTTPS redirection.
>
> After a Vapor deployment is completed, Vapor will provide you with
> CNAME records for the domain(s) associated with your environment.
> These records will point the domain to your Lambda application. You
> should manually add these values as CNAME records within the
> Cloudflare DNS dashboard.
>
> In addition, when using Cloudflare, you should set your Cloudflare SSL
> / TLS mode to "Full". The "Always Use HTTPS" configuration option may
> be found under the SSL / TLS menu's "Edge Certificates" tab.

A simple solution would be to use Gateway Version 1.